# Is my Simpson's rule calculator correct (java)?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, calculator, precision

I'm supposed to calculate

[image]

using Simpson's  rule, with 4 sub intervals.

I surely do not want do it by hand so I have tried to write that algorithm in Java.

The formula for Simpson's rule is

[image]

And here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Locale;
public class Simpson {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
        //e= 2.718281828459045 to copy paste
        System.out.println("Interval a: ");
        double aInt = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Interval b: ");
        double bInt = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("How many sub intervals: ");
        double teilInt = input.nextDouble();
        double intervaldistance = (bInt-aInt)/teilInt;
        System.out.println("h = "+"("+bInt+"-"+aInt+") / "+teilInt+ " = "+intervaldistance);
        double total = 0;
        System.out.println("");
        double totalSum=0;

        for(double i=0; i<teilInt; i++) {
            bInt = aInt+intervaldistance;
            printInterval(aInt, bInt);
            total = prod1(aInt, bInt);
            total = total*prod2(aInt, bInt);
            aInt = bInt;
            System.out.println(total);
            totalSum=totalSum+total;
            total=0;
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Result: "+totalSum);
    }
    static double prod1(double a, double b) { // first product of simpson rule; (b-a) / 6
        double res1 = (b-a)/6;
        return res1;
    }
    static double prod2(double a, double b) { // second pproduct of simpson rule
        double res2 = Math.log(a)+4*Math.log((a+b)/2)+Math.log(b);
        return res2;
    }
    static void printInterval(double a, double b) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("["+a+"; "+b+"]"); 
    }
}

Output for 4 sub intervals:

[1.0; 1.4295704571147612]
0.08130646125926948

[1.4295704571147612; 1.8591409142295223]
0.21241421690076787

[1.8591409142295223; 2.2887113713442835]
0.31257532785558795

[2.2887113713442835; 2.7182818284590446]
0.39368288949073565

Result: 0.9999788955063609
```

Now If I compare my solution with other online calculators (http://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-2/simpsons-rule-calculator/?f=ln+%28x%29&a=1&b=e&n=4&steps=on), it differs.. But I don't see why mine should be wrong.

My solution is `0.9999788955063609`, online solution is `0.999707944567103`

Maybe there is a mistake I made? But I have double checked everything and couldn't find.

Comment: Didn't read through the code that thoroughly, but you're mixing integers (`6`,`4`,`2`) with `double`s and this might cause rounding errors. Try to define them as `double`s  instead (`6.0`,`4.0`,`2.0`) and see if it has an effect.

Comment: The link you listed has n=4. When I changed the url to have n=16 rather than n=4, I got Answer: 0.999998619003165.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I had a good feeling when I read your comment but it sadly didn't help :( Anyway that's really good to know and I will be aware of that when I write more code like that.

Comment: @RyanStout The task is for 16 sub intervals. But in this question I took 4 intervals to not make this question even longer.

Comment: Your question says you ran with 16 intervals and you gave a link that uses 4 intervals. Maybe update the question?

Comment: While the algorithm looks good, this may not get you many marks in the test  or exam. The test is probably looking for the composite rule h/3( f(a_0)+4 f(a_1)+2 f(a_2)+ 4 f(a_3) + f(a_4)). To get marks they will need to see the five f(a_n) calculated and an expression involving these values. I did my entire linear algebra course using computers but didn't get great marks even though it helped me understand it well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be accumulating the rounding error by doing b_n = a_{n} + interval many times.
Instead you could be using an inductive approach, where you say a_n = a_0 + n*interval, since this only involves introducing a rounding error once.

I will test with actual numbers to confirm and flesh out the answer in a little bit, but in the meantime you can watch this explanation about accumulation of error from [handmade hero](https://hero.handmade.network/episode/code/day146#3011)

---

<sub>PS. As a bonus, you get to watch an excerpt from handmade hero!</sub>

**UPDATE**: I had a look at your link. While the problem I described above *does* apply, the difference in precision is small (you'll get the answer 0.9999788955063612 instead). The reason for the discrepancy in your case is that the formula used in your online calculator is a slightly different variant in terms of notation, which treats the interval [a,b] as 2h. In other words, your 4 intervals is equivalent to 8 intervals in their calculation.

If you put 8 rectangles in that webpage you'll get the same result as the (more accurate) number here:

> Answer: 0.999978895506362.

See a better explanation of the notation used on that webpage [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpsonsRule.html)

Answer (score 2):

I changed your delta calculation to the top to so that you don't calculate the delta over and over again. You were also not applying the right multipliers for the odd and even factors, as well as not applying the right formula for deltaX since it has to be: ((a-b)/n) /3

```
double deltaX = ((bInt-aInt)/teilInt)/3;

for(int i=0; i<=teilInt; i++) { //changed to <= to include the last interval
    bInt = aInt+intervaldistance;
    printInterval(aInt, bInt);
    total = prod2(aInt, bInt, i+1, teilInt); //added the current interval and n. The interval is +1 to work well with the even and odds
    totalSum += total;
    aInt = bInt;
    System.out.println(total);
}   

System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Result: "+ (totalSum*deltaX)); //multiplication with deltaX is now here
```

To account for the right factor of f(x) i changed the prod2 to:

```
static double prod2(double a, double b, int interval, double n) {
    int multiplier = 1;
    if (interval > 0 && interval <= n){
          //applying the right multiplier to f(x) given the current interval
          multiplier = (interval % 2 == 0) ? 4 : 2; 
    }

    return multiplier * Math.log(a);        
}
```

Now it yields the correct result:

[image]